# ASP.NET Core Identity: the base class (IdentityUser, IdentityRole, IdentityUserRole e.t.c.) Implementation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

### Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, 
            UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
        {
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
                        : base(options)
            {
            }


            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            }
        }
```

### Entity classes of Identity:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole, RoleClaim>
    {
    }

    public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class RoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class UserToken : IdentityUserToken<Guid>
    {
    }
```

### Class `Startup.cs`:

```
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                                 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
             .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
             .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When the application starts, it throws the following exception:

> GenericArguments[0], 'del.Models.ApplicationUser', on
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`4[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey]'
>   violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

[image: Exception img]
How to solve this problem? Classes "`UserRole`, `RoleClaim`" is needed.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to use the same thing except for using int instead of Guid and nothing seems to work in my case as well. TIA

Comment: Follow this discussion: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1082#issuecomment-273514725

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue just today.  I am heavily extending the Identity system to support things that I need in my application.  One of the things I noticed is that since the IdentityUser has A LOT of different derived classes, it is not always as simple as overriding just "IdentityUser<>".

Having said that, the exception is getting thrown in the ExtensionMethod "AddEntityFrameworkStores()".  The reason for this is that that extension method also uses a private helper method that dynamically creates a generic type:

```
userStoreType = typeof(UserStore<,,,>).MakeGenericType(userType, roleType, contextType, keyType);
```

UserStore<> also has a lot of different generic signatures.  I created my own derived UserStore (ApplicationUserStore) so that I could create my own ApplicationUserRole.  In doing that, the creation of the generic type would no longer work.  I had to create my own version of the extension method that was:

```
userStoreType = typeof(ApplicationUserStore<,,,>).MakeGenericType(userType, roleType, contextType, keyType);
```

Now, this my not be your "exact" issue, but I'm 99% sure this is it.  You may need to create your own derived UserStore using the following signature:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext, Guid>
{
  ...
}
```

Then create a new Extensions method class that duplicates the original but changes the UserStore creation.

```
public static class IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions2
{        
    public static IdentityBuilder AddEntityFrameworkStores2<TContext>(this IdentityBuilder builder)
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        builder.Services.TryAdd(GetDefaultServices(builder.UserType, builder.RoleType, typeof(TContext)));
        return builder;
    }

    public static IdentityBuilder AddEntityFrameworkStores2<TContext, TKey>(this IdentityBuilder builder)
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
    {
        builder.Services.TryAdd(GetDefaultServices(builder.UserType, builder.RoleType, typeof(TContext), typeof(TKey)));
        return builder;
    }

    private static IServiceCollection GetDefaultServices(Type userType, Type roleType, Type contextType, Type keyType = null)
    {
        Type userStoreType;
        Type roleStoreType;
        keyType = keyType ?? typeof(string);
        userStoreType = typeof(ApplicationUserStore<,,,>).MakeGenericType(userType, roleType, contextType, keyType);
        roleStoreType = typeof(ApplicationRoleStore<,,>).MakeGenericType(roleType, contextType, keyType);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddScoped(
            typeof(IUserStore<>).MakeGenericType(userType),
            userStoreType);
        services.AddScoped(
            typeof(IRoleStore<>).MakeGenericType(roleType),
            roleStoreType);
        return services;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore` is as following ([source](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/UserStore-TUser/)):

```
public class UserStore<TUser> 
    : UserStore<TUser, IdentityRole, DbContext, string>, 
    IUserLoginStore<TUser>, 
    IUserRoleStore<TUser>, 
    IUserClaimStore<TUser>, 
    IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, 
    IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>, 
    IUserEmailStore<TUser>, 
    IUserLockoutStore<TUser>, 
    IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser>, 
    IQueryableUserStore<TUser>, 
    IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>, 
    IUserAuthenticationTokenStore<TUser>, 
    IUserStore<TUser>, 
    IDisposable 
    where TUser : IdentityUser<string>, new ()
```

Pay attention to `TUser` constraint, `TUser` must be `IdentityUser<string>` or it should derive from `IdentityUser<string>`. In your case you declared `ApplicationUser` to derive from `IdentityUser<Guid, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>`. It is the reason of exception. You should use `string` as a primary key.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I also think as you, that problem in IdentityUser<string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>. Because UserStore requires IdentityUser<string>, but not IdentityUser<string, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin>. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty simple. just mention you Appuser role and key type like this

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUserModel, RoleModel, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
                    : base(options)
        {
        }
```

and in startup

```
 services.AddIdentity<SameUserModelhere, sameRoleModelhere>();
```

and it will work fine.